# Android: On clicking Button or TextView my application showing ANR

Tags: android, multithreading, button, onclick

i am trying to do some heavy task on clicking a button and i want to change the state of the button changed instantly when i click that button but its not happening. Its changing only when the task get completed.I guess i should use multi threading as i am using interaction with webservices too.

any better solution please.

Comment: This question is pointless, because you've answered it yourself. You'll obviously need to use another thread.

Comment: @avital do some editing brother and make it to the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you shoud better do yoour heavy task in `AsyncTask`, which is designed for performing tasks in background and notifying UI thread when it's needed.

Look at this [article about threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) from Google and use examples from it to rewrite your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the part of the code for changing the button before the heavy lifting code in the onClickListener, then it would do the UI part first.

Comment: If we don't put "heavy" code outside of UI thread, we'll still have ANR on interacting with app.

Comment: I upvoted you're response (it is obviously the better approach) I was just trying to answer the specific question asked